# How to bind windows key combo

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

I have no idea if this is possible, but when using a powershell/windows terminal instance, I'd like to bind the key combo Win+E to open a file explorer at the current path I have open in my terminal.

I've found that the `explorer` command does this, but I don't know if it is possible to bind system wide key combos like Win+E to do actions that grab data (the current path) from a running program. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you could do `e` => `Enter` to open File Explorer at the current PowerShell path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> combo is already used by Windows,
so is not the best choice. This answer uses
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead. The below code will enable you to press the key combo at the PowerShell prompt and open Explorer at the current path. It requires the PSReadLine Module.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key ctrl+e `
    -BriefDescription ExplorerAtCurrentPath `
    -LongDescription "Open Explorer at Current Path" `
    -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process -FilePath 'explorer.exe' -ArgumentList "/separate , $($pwd.Path)" -Wait
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> combo is already used by Windows,
so is not the best choice. This answer uses
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead,
using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

It will work for any process that is currently holding the focus.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the below script in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Here is the script:

```
!e::
WinGet, process, PID, A
MsgBox, %process%
curdir := GetProcessCurrentDirectory(process)
MsgBox, %curdir%
Run, explorer %curdir%
return

GetProcessCurrentDirectory(PID)  {
   static PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION := 0x400, PROCESS_VM_READ := 0x10, STATUS_SUCCESS := 0
   
   hProc := DllCall("OpenProcess", UInt, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, Int, 0, UInt, PID, Ptr)
   (A_Is64bitOS && DllCall("IsWow64Process", Ptr, hProc, UIntP, IsWow64))
   if (!A_Is64bitOS || IsWow64)
      PtrSize := 4, PtrType := "UInt", pPtr := "UIntP"
   else
      PtrSize := 8, PtrType := "Int64", pPtr := "Int64P"
   offsetCURDIR := 4*4 + PtrSize*5
   
   hModule := DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "str", "Ntdll", Ptr)
   if (A_PtrSize < PtrSize)  {            ; <<—— script 32, target process 64
      if !QueryInformationProcess := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hModule, AStr, "NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64", Ptr)
         failed := "NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64"
      if !ReadProcessMemory := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hModule, AStr, "NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64", Ptr)
         failed := "NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64"
      info := 0, szPBI := 48, offsetPEB := 8
   }
   else  {
      if !QueryInformationProcess := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hModule, AStr, "NtQueryInformationProcess", Ptr)
         failed := "NtQueryInformationProcess"
      ReadProcessMemory := "ReadProcessMemory"
      if (A_PtrSize > PtrSize)            ; <<—— script 64, target process 32
         info := 26, szPBI := 8, offsetPEB := 0
      else                                ; <<—— script and target process have the same bitness
         info := 0, szPBI := PtrSize * 6, offsetPEB := PtrSize
   }
   if failed  {
      DllCall("CloseHandle", Ptr, hProc)
      MsgBox, Failed to get pointer to %failed%
      Return
   }
   VarSetCapacity(PBI, 48, 0)
   if DllCall(QueryInformationProcess, Ptr, hProc, UInt, info, Ptr, &PBI, UInt, szPBI, UIntP, bytes) != STATUS_SUCCESS  {
      DllCall("CloseHandle", Ptr, hProc)
      Return
   }
   pPEB := NumGet(&PBI + offsetPEB, PtrType)
   DllCall(ReadProcessMemory, Ptr, hProc, PtrType, pPEB + PtrSize * 4, pPtr, pRUPP, PtrType, PtrSize, UIntP, bytes)
   DllCall(ReadProcessMemory, Ptr, hProc, PtrType, pRUPP + offsetCURDIR, UShortP, szBuff, PtrType, 2, UIntP, bytes)
   DllCall(ReadProcessMemory, Ptr, hProc, PtrType, pRUPP + offsetCURDIR + PtrSize, pPtr, pCURDIR, PtrType, PtrSize, UIntP, bytes)
   
   VarSetCapacity(buff, szBuff, 0)
   DllCall(ReadProcessMemory, Ptr, hProc, PtrType, pCURDIR, Ptr, &buff, PtrType, szBuff, UIntP, bytes)
   DllCall("CloseHandle", Ptr, hProc)
   Return currentDirPath := StrGet(&buff, "UTF-16")
}
```

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)